Event Listeners only working on initial page, not on AJAX pagination reload
I have a loop grid which works and filters fine, with a dynamic pop-up box which appears when a container is clicked. My issue is that this only works on the initially loaded items in my grid, and does not work when page 2, 3 etc. is selected - pagination is loaded with AJAX.
Is there a way to have my event listeners to remain active after the AJAX call? I am a complete beginner with this but would appreciate any help in what I might be missing.
Thank you,
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    function attachShowBioEventListeners() {
        // Select all buttons that have an ID starting with 'button'
        const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=button]');
        
        // Add event listeners to each button
        buttons.forEach(button => {
            button.removeEventListener('click', handleShowBioClick); // Remove any existing listeners to avoid duplicates
            button.addEventListener('click', handleShowBioClick);
        });

        // Add event listener to each close icon
        document.querySelectorAll('.close-icon').forEach(icon => {
            icon.removeEventListener('click', handleCloseIconClick); // Remove any existing listeners to avoid duplicates
            icon.addEventListener('click', handleCloseIconClick);
        });
    }

    function handleShowBioClick(event) {
        const button = event.currentTarget;
        const postID = button.id.replace('button', ''); // Extract the post ID from the button ID
        const containerID = 'container' + postID; // Construct the container ID

        // Hide all containers
        document.querySelectorAll('.container').forEach(container => {
            container.style.display = 'none';
        });

        // Show the specific container related to the clicked button
        const containerToShow = document.getElementById(containerID);
        if (containerToShow) {
            containerToShow.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

    function handleCloseIconClick() {
        // Hide all containers when a close icon is clicked
        document.querySelectorAll('.container').forEach(container => {
            container.style.display = 'none';
        });
    }

    // Initial attachment of event listeners
    attachShowBioEventListeners();

    // Reattach event listeners after the filter is applied
    document.querySelectorAll('.e-filter-item').forEach(filterButton => {
        filterButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
            setTimeout(attachShowBioEventListeners, 500); // Wait a bit for the DOM to update
        });
    });
});

</script>

I have the event listener added to the document which does allow everything to run correctly and from looking at other similar issues this has been the resolution, but this still does not seem to work right.
